# How do I clear a specific player head in 1.17?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a command that clears only specific player heads and a specific amount. I tried using this:

```
clear shaeno minecraft:player_head{SkullOwner:shaeno} 1
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command should work:

```
/clear @p minecraft:player_head{SkullOwner:{Name:"shaeno"}} 1
```

The `SkullOwner` tag was updated to have a more robust structure. If you want to identify player head by username, you should use `{Name:username_here}`.

Hope this helps out!